# main() calls main() recursively - gdb backtrace does not show multiple main() frames - Why?

Tags: c, gdb

I am calling `main()` inside `main()`, recursively for 10 times. Now while debugging using `gdb` (bt/backtrace), I don't see multiple frames for `main()`. Why?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

     static int i;
     int num=100;

     if(i>10)
       return 0;
     else {
       i++;
       num++;
       main();
       printf("\n%d",num); 
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

**This is documented behaviour of `gdb`, and it [is (supposed to be) configurable](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Backtrace.html).**

When I compile your code with `gcc 4.7.2` (`-O3`), I get the following assembly:

```
_main:
LFB1:
        movl    _i.2134(%rip), %eax
        cmpl    $10, %eax
        jle     L6
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        ret
L6:
        addl    $1, %eax
        pushq   %rdx
LCFI0:
        movl    %eax, _i.2134(%rip)
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        call    _main                    ; <=== recursive call
        popq    %rcx
LCFI1:
        movl    $101, %esi
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        leaq    LC0(%rip), %rdi
        jmp     _printf
LFE1:
```

This refutes the hypothesis that the recursive call is optimized away.

Now, if I load the binary into `gdb` and set a breakpoint on `main()`, it gets hit repeatedly. When I examine the registers, `%rsp` is getting decremented with each call, so there are clearly stack frames associated with each `main()`.

Nonetheless, `bt` only shows a single frame:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000100000f50 in main ()
```

(In this case, I know there are three `main()` frames and not just one.)

I therefore conclude that this has something to do with `gdb` itself.

Upon further investigation, it turns out that this behaviour is [documented](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Backtrace.html):

> Most programs have a standard user entry point—a place where system libraries and startup code transition into user code. For C this is `main`. When `gdb` finds the entry function in a backtrace it will terminate the backtrace, to avoid tracing into highly system-specific (and generally uninteresting) code.

When I set the following in `gdb`:

```
set backtrace past-main on
set backtrace past-entry on
```

it starts showing two `main()` frames. For some reason, it's still not going any deeper.

Answer (score 2):

Your question has nothing to do with the fact that you use `main` for that.

A simple recursive program as you finally care to show us in a comment can easily be optimized by the compiler by not doing recursion at all. In your case it is even more simple that usual, since you have a predefined recursion depth of `10`. This can easily be unrolled by the compiler to static code.

Comment: I tried by disabling the optimization during compilation but again one frame only during debugging.

Comment: hum .. gdb disass does show a   `callq  0x40050c <main>` instruction. Could it be that gdb purposely hide function calls above `main()`  ?

Comment: Have a look in the assembler, for gcc e.g this is option `-S` instead of `-c`. And first of all use another function name for recursion to see if it is coming from there.

Comment: By default gdb hide the fun call before main but if we want we can make gdb to show those fun call as well. But here in this case i want to see multiple main() frame not fun who called main().

Comment: It's possible that gdb's stack unwinding code stops once it found the first frame within `main()`.  Try moving your code into another function, disable optimization and see whether that fixes it.

Comment: @MartinBaulig's guess seems right. For me, backtrace always stops at `main`, even when that particular frame of `main` is called by a function *other than* `main`.

Comment: If i move my code to other function it will sure work. Why its not working in current case as per gdb manual(call stack) it should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
Here is the Answer for my own Question.
(gdb) set backtrace past-main on
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4004b0: file recursion.c, line 5.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /nobackup/arjprasa/C/gdb/a.out

Breakpoint 1, main () at recursion.c:5
5               int num=100;
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 1, main () at recursion.c:5
5               int num=100;
(gdb) bt
#0  main () at recursion.c:5
#1  0x00000000004004df in main () at recursion.c:12
#2  0x00000034d091c4cb in __libc_start_main () from /lib64/tls/libc.so.6
#3  0x000000000040041a in _start ()
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 1, main () at recursion.c:5
5               int num=100;
(gdb) bt
#0  main () at recursion.c:5
#1  0x00000000004004df in main () at recursion.c:12
#2  0x00000000004004df in main () at recursion.c:12
#3  0x00000034d091c4cb in __libc_start_main () from /lib64/tls/libc.so.6
#4  0x000000000040041a in _start ()
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 1, main () at recursion.c:5
5               int num=100;
(gdb) bt
#0  main () at recursion.c:5
#1  0x00000000004004df in main () at recursion.c:12
#2  0x00000000004004df in main () at recursion.c:12
#3  0x00000000004004df in main () at recursion.c:12
#4  0x00000034d091c4cb in __libc_start_main () from /lib64/tls/libc.so.6
#5  0x000000000040041a in _start ()
(gdb)
```